# How to use NSDecimalNumber class methods with RubyMotion?

Tags: ios, rubymotion, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to convert these lines of code in Objective-C to RubyMotion, but it's not working.

```
 NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"12.34"];

  NSDecimalNumber *shipping = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"5.99"];

  NSDecimalNumber *tax = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"2.50"];

  NSDecimalNumber *total = [[subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping] decimalNumberByAdding:tax];
```

This is what I tried with RubyMotion, but it's not working:

```
subtotal = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString('12.34')

shipping = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString('5.99')

tax = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString('2.50') 

total = (subtotal.decimalNumberByAdding(shipping)).decimalNumberByAdding(tax)
```

And this is the error that I get:

undefined method `decimalNumberByAdding' for 12.3400001525879:Float (NoMethodError)

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think RubyMotion convert `subtotal` to ruby float and it don't have method `decimalNumberByAdding`

Comment: According to the RubyMotion API documentation it does have a method decimalNumberByAdding here is the API documentation [link](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/NSDecimalNumber.html)

Comment: Yes `NSDecimalNumber` does have that method. but float class in Ruby doesn't. RubyMotion automatically convert `NSNumber` to float for you, and because `NSDecimalNumber` is subclass of `NSNumber`, it does the same thing for you too. so `subtotal` is no longer a type of `NSDecimalNumber`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just do this:

```
subtotal = "12.34".to_f
shipping = "5.99".to_f
tax = "2.50".to_f

total = subtotal + shipping + tax
```

Just be wary of these weird conversions. Maybe `#round(2)` can help.

```
(main)> subtotal = "12.34".to_f
=> 12.3400001525879
(main)> shipping = "5.99".to_f
=> 5.98999977111816
(main)> tax = "2.50".to_f
=> 2.5
(main)> total = subtotal + shipping + tax
=> 20.8299942016602
```

As suggested by [matthewsinclair](https://twitter.com/matthewsinclair), it's also best practice to just use integers and store everything as cents. That way you don't get any of these conversion issues.

Comment: Thanks @willrax for the help. I think I'm going to go like in your example and then use the #round(2) like total.round(2) I'm integrating PayPal-iOS-SDK in my RubyMotion app, hopefully this will work. I will report later if this worked.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at this: https://github.com/skandragon/stringify_float